# cleaner way of moving the total count logic in a ruby helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is kinda of a stupid question, but i was kinda looking for a nice way to put this in helper method or something.
 I looping through games and get the total and win count methods for each event. 
 And adding the whole thing together and displaying.

```
- count = 0
- win_count = 0
- game.results.each do |result|
  - count+=result.total
  - win_count+=result.wins

="total wins#{win_count}"
="total#{count}"
```

Is there a better ruby way of doing it?

Note: I would need a solution without using a model.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a better way, and the better way is to use Model's method, instead of a helper. Avoid helper when you can.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results

  def winning_count
    wining_results.count
  end

  def winding_results
    results.where(win: true)
  end

  def results_count
    results.count
  end

end
```

Usage in view

```
@game.results_count
@game.winning_count
```

Comment: the problem is there is no model for this app. an external service is retuning the results in a json.

Comment: @newbie you could create a thin wrapper (a presentation model) around the json response data. Add any logic you need into the presentation model. I use this approach frequently.

Comment: agree with @WizardofOgz use a service object/presenter. great article on that here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ (specifically #2)